# Can this circuit oscillate?

Tags: oscillator

At a test, I was given the following circuit and i was told that it will oscillate and it was required to mention the condition and frequency of oscillation :
[image]

I tried thinking in many ways but i always conclude that it won't oscillate !

so I tried simulating it using Cadence OrCad using different combinations of R and C values, but the circuit didn't oscillate.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: You didn't bother to state why you don't think it will oscillate, or what values of R and C you used.

Comment: I had no problem making it oscillate in LTspice. I don't know OrCAD, but I needed to step the power supplies of the op-amps.

Comment: @Bort i don't think it will oscillate because the phase shift across the loop isn't zero.

i tried using
R=10k C=10nF,
R=10k C=100uF,
R=1k C=10nF,
R=100k C=10nF,

Comment: @Renan what values for R,C and the supply are you using ?

Comment: @Loksza +/- 12 V, R = 1k, C = 10 nF. I put my schematic here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cabibyh7reppziv/q.asc?dl=0

Comment: @Renan thank you. I've tried R=1k,C=10nF and it didn't work although my schematic and simulation is perfectly fine.Unfortunately, I can't run your schematic because i don't have LT Spice.

Answer (score 0):

They made a mistake. Its a negative feedback loop.

**in fact I would urge you to challenge your Prof.**

If you put a sweep generator on the U1 + input instead of ground each op amp becomes a unity gain + voltage follower and since the output is fed back to the Vin- is the same as the input there is NO feedback current (zilch , nada , nothing)  , hence RC does NOTHING. and with no sweep the output is same as Vin+ on U1 .. meaning 0V.

Beware if you do, he may invite to be a post grad student for your intelligent question. and if he doesn't understand refuse his offer. (ROTFL)

Comment: I happen to miss the unity gain in U2; can you elaborate?

Comment: Opps must have been a hair on my screen in the feedback loop

Comment: Even if each OA has a phase margin of 60 deg the output will always be 0V with a transient instability added with LPF feedback .\ If you FM sweep  Vin1(+) and look at Vout2 it will be a high gain BPF between HPF and loop BW of OAs.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought . Now i'm relieved, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Now go ask Prof why he made a BandPass high gain filter an OSC question on test? with no assumptions on phase margin.  If U2 was unity gain like the hair on my screen across output to Vin2(-) then my original answer is valid unity gain thruout.  but open loop just becomes a BW limited BPF.  But for Ideal Op Amps Vout 1= Vout2 =0V